# how to get part of the path name and add it to the index

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I currently have a file name like this.
[SERIALNUMBER][2014_12_04][00_45_22][141204T014214]AB_DEF.log

i basically want to extract the year from the file (2014) and add it to the index name in logstash conf file.`logstash.conf`
Below is my conf file.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/ABC/DEF/HJK/LOGS/**/*"
         start_position => beginning
        type => syslog
    }
}
filter {


    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }




}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    index => "type1logs"
    }
    stdout {}    
}
```

Please help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you get a field called 'path'.  You can then run another grok{} filter, using 'path' as input and extracting the data you want.

Based on your use of COMBINEDAPACHELOG in your existing config, your log entries already have the date.  It's a more common practice to use this timestamp field in the date{} filter to change the @timestamp field.  Then, the default elasticsearch{} output config will create an index called "logstash-YYYY.MM.DD".

Having daily indexes like this (usually) makes data retention easier.